# In AS3, how can you override the setters and getters for the [] operator?

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance, dictionary, operators, overloading

I know that AS3 doesn't normally allow method or operator overloading, but I do think I've seen a workaround before for the [] operator.  Basically I'm trying to either inherit from or wrap around a Dictionary - I don't necessarily care which - and create slightly special behavior for that operator, namely in the case it's used twice in a row (object[x][y]).  Isn't there some sort of special workaround or loophole I can use for this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override `getters` and `setters` using the [`Proxy`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) class.

If you extend `Proxy` and make your class `dynamic`, you'll be able to override these methods:

- [`getProperty()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html#getProperty%28%29)
- [`setProperty()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html#setProperty%28%29)

Using the `[]` operator will apply to this as expected (i.e. `thing.x` will be the same as `thing["x"]` if you override the getter for `x`).

If you look at the links I've added above to the Proxy class, there are blocks of example code that demonstrate how to implement what you're trying to do.